# Dynamically add or remove table rows with jQuery or Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, symfony

This is the code I have. I'm using Symfony/Twig to pass the variables and translation strings in (if anyone was unsure what the `{{`, `}}`, `{% trans %}` etc was for).

Please see the line where I have the `glyphicon glyphicon-camera` - what I want is for the user to be able to click this, and a new row appears directly below containing the contents of `row.getPhoto()` - the icon will only appear if `row.getPhoto()` is not null, so therefore clicking it will always mean there is content to show.

Likewise, clicking the photo icon again will make the row disappear.

How can I do this? I'm not sure if I should use jQuery or Angular (I am using both in other places in the project, so both are easily available for me). Any comments welcome, thank you.

```
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th width="10%">{% trans %} header.item {% endtrans %}</th>
        <th width="60%">{% trans %} header.action {% endtrans %}</th>
        <th width="10%">{% trans %} header.option1 {% endtrans %}</th>
        <th width="10%">{% trans %} header.option2 {% endtrans %}</th>
        <th width="10%">{% trans %} header.option3 {% endtrans %}</th>
    </tr>

    {% for row in showRows(allItems) %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ row.getItem() }}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{ row.getAction() }} {% if row.getPhoto() is not null %} <span class="pull-right show-hide-photo glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span>{% endif %}
            </td>

            <td>
                {% if row.getOption1() %}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>{% endif %}
            </td>

            <td>
                {% if row.getOption2() %}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>{% endif %}
            </td>

            <td>
                {% if row.getOption3() %}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>{% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Only jQuery I have right now is this, to make the icon appear like a link when hovered over:

```
    // Photo button
    $('.show-hide-photo').css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

Comment: row.getPhoto() is a link? btw you can use row.photo also less code, if its a link i will give you a complete answer, i first need to know what is it

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass symphony2 variables on javascript code, so you can have a scirpt with something along the lines of:

```
<scirpt>
$(.glyphicon).click(function(){
     $(.Some-other-class).toggle()
});
</script>
```

You can have the .Some-other-class div element or td element starting as hidden and with variables in it (like you did in your static html code).

Comment: How do I actually add and remove the new row though - such that it appears directly below the row where the icon was clicked?

Comment: You can add the row as html code, specify the '<style display:none>' and then when you call [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), the [display](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) will toggle the visiblity on and off. You can read more about it on the API links.

Comment: Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbv3y2kt/) explaining what I mean. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Should the `id` be on the `td` or the `tr` though?

Comment: Also, given the rows are generated dynamically I won't know which ID to toggle. I've decided to name the IDs as like, `photo1`, `photo2`, etc where the number is equal to `row.getItem()` (which is an integer). How can I pass that ID into the jQuery such that it knows which row to toggle? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the css pointer in the js use it in a css class to have it when the page load not when the user click.

And for your click you can do something like this if you photo is a link then :

first use in your twig a `<img src="{{row.photo}}" alt="" style="display:none;"/>` whenever you want to put the images.

then inside your js in the click photo button

```
$('.show-hide-photo').on('click', function(){

   $(this).closest('tr').find('img').toggle();

});
```

`$(this)` is your show-hide-photo button , `closest('tr')` will look for the  tag which contain your button then `find('img')` will go find the  tag inside that (row) in that case you wont need to bother with ids to select right row etc..